# Changing max_length on a CharField for a ModelForm

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have defined the max_length on a field to be 50 in the model definition. When a form is created it takes those attributes to make the fields, but I would like to overwrite that max_length for that specific form without changing the model itself.

**This is what I have in my model**

```
text_field01 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
text_field02 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
```

I tried overwriting the widget with a new widget in my forms.py but that threw an error. I also tried it in the **init** but that seemed to have no effect. I am a bit stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

At first I tried setting the widgets in class meta as shown below.

```
widgets = {
'text_field01': forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This produced an error "CharField" object has no attribute 'is_hidden'

Then I tried doing it in **init** as shown below.

```
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(AutomationForm, self).__init__(data=data, files=files, *args, **kwargs)
            if self.instance:
                if self.fields['text_field01']:
                    self.fields['text_field01'].max_length = 2
```

Which simply had no effect.

Comment: Can you show what you did in the `ModelForm`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem check the edits

Comment: The `CharField` is *not* a widget, but a form fields. A widget is how you render it at html, a FormField is how the form validates it. Does the given anwser helps?

Comment: This helps me understand why I was getting the error when trying to simply change it through the Widgets but I still not sure how to solve my issue.

Comment: no, because a widget does not validate `max_length`, a widget is constructed to render something like `<input ...>` at the page (and uses the form field to get information about that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `ModelForm`, and override the value for the [**`max_length=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.max_length):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text_field01 = forms.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

The `max_length` you define in the `ModelForm` can only be less than or equal to the one in the `Model` itself, since validation in the model has to succeed as well.